# Reset a .NET dictionary keeping the keys

Tags: .net, c#-3.0, containers

I have a `Dictionary<K,V>` with a known, non changing set of keys.
I would like to reset the dictionary, but keeping the values of the keys, changing only the values to `null`.

I can first call `Clear()` on the dictionary and re-Adding the pair with `null` as a value, there should be a better way.

Comment: better performance or better readability?

Comment: Both would be great, but I'll take readability if there is a choice to be made.

Comment: If you know the size of the dictionary ahead of time, you can get a performance boost by passing the known size into the constructor.  This will prevent the need for the resize operations.  If you want to set the values to null, you will have to visit each value and set them individually.

Comment: well, it would be appreciated if the downvoters could explain their vote.

Comment: @HansPassant of course. I did only iterate on pairs and could not edit the value part as it is readonly inside the foreach loop. Thanks!

Comment: and you get collection was modified error @HansPassant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use keys and set all values to null

for example

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
d.Keys.ToList().ForEach(x => d[x] = null);
```

here is a list of extension methods you can use, choose which suites better in your situation and test their performance

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<K, V> ResetValues<K, V>(this Dictionary<K, V> dic)
    {
        dic.Keys.ToList().ForEach(x => dic[x] = default(V));
        return dic;
    }

    public static Dictionary<K,V> ResetValuesWithNewDictionary<K, V>(this Dictionary<K, V> dic)
    {
        return dic.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => default(V), dic.Comparer);
    }

}
```

and use it like

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
d.ResetValues().Select(..../*method chaining is supported*/);
```

or

```
d = d.ResetValuesWithNewDictionary().Select(..../*method chaining is supported*/);
```

Comment: The "WithNewDictionary" version should probably pass the Comparer property of the original dictionary to the appropriate ToDictionary overload, in order to preserve the comparison semantics (e.g. case-sensitivity).